# Use promise to wait for database operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, generator, co

I have a function that calls another function, which connects to a database to get some value. Until the execution is completed, I cannot proceed further as that value is to used for another transaction on the database.

I am using `yield` to determine the completion of that method, and `promise` to resolve or reject the response. This is how I am doing it:

```
co(function*() {
  rec.x = yield getX(a, b);
  //use rec to update something else
  conn.update(rec);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error(err.stack)
});

function getX(a, b) {
  return conn.getVal(a, b);
}

exports.getVal = function(a, b) {
  return sql.connect(connStr).then(function() {
    return new sql.Request()
      .input('a', sql.VarChar(100), a)
      .input('b', sql.VarChar(50), b)
      .execute('someProc').then(function(recordSet) {
        return Promise.resolve(recordSet[0][0]);
      });
  });
};
```

I am getting this error:

```
ConnectionError: Connection is closed.
    at node_modules/mssql/lib/main.js:1613:17
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:417:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:346:13)
```

**edit**

Connection string:

```
Uname:pass@server/database
```

Comment: _at node_modules/mssql/lib/main.js: **1613** :17_ which line is number 1613 in the code you posted

Comment: Does the request work without going through the generator/yield? Meaning, if you call `getVal` function directly, does it work?

Comment: Can you share your connection string in the post?

Comment: @Freyday yes. The request works fine without yield..

Comment: What happens if you assign `sql.connect(conStr)` to a `connection` variable, then pass `connection` into `sql.Request()` like `sql.Request(connection)`? Do you get the same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending hours on figuring out this vodoo of `mssql`. It seems like `mssql` does not handle concurrent `connection` well enough. Therefore, using `setTimeout` on making connection requests solved the problem for me.

If it helps anyone, this is what I did:

```
exports.getVal = function(obj, cb) {
    var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('connected..');
        var request = new sql.Request(connection);
        request.input('a', sql.VarChar(100), obj.a);
        request.input('b', sql.VarChar(50), obj.b);
        request.execute('proc', function (err, recordSet, returnValue, affected) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            cb(recordSet[0][0]);
        });
    });
};
```

This is how I call:

```
 setTimeout(function(){
                                getVal(rec, function(obj){
                                    console.log(obj);
                                });
                            }, 500);
```